# Why is this combinatorics equation correct?

Tags: combinatorics

Jaynes posits the following equation without any explanation:

$$\sum_{R=0}^{N}\binom Rr\binom{N-R}{n-r}=\binom{N+1}{n+1}$$
**I don't understand why this would be the case. Is there a proof for this?**

assumptions are: $0\leq r\leq R \leq N$, and $r\leq n\leq N$

Comment: As written, your question doesn't make sense. The left hand side has a term where $R=0,$ but you say that $0<r\leq R$ below.

Comment: The first term of a sum, which @RideTheWavelet mentioned above, has $R=0$, which implies $r=0$, so you can substitute that in the whole sum — unless there is some other $\sum_r$ missing there...

Comment: I believe the original question meant to have $0\leq r\leq R.$

Comment: yes, it was supposed to be less than or equal to. sorry. This resolves the problem doesn't it?

Answer (score 5):

$\binom{N+1}{n+1}$ counts the number of subsets of $\{0,\dots,N\}$ of size $n+1$.

$\binom{R}{r}\binom{N-R}{n-r}$ counts such subsets where the $r+1$st element, in sorted order, is $R$. That is, a subset of the form $$0\leq a_1<a_2<\dots<a_r<a_{r+1}=R<a_{r+2}<\cdots a_{n+1}.$$

Comment: $\binom{R}{r}$ counts $r+1$-subsets of $\{0,1,2,\dots,R\}$ with largest element $R$, @RideTheWavelet And $\binom{N-R}{n-r}$ counts $n-r$-subsets of $\{R+1,R+2,\dots,N+1\}$.

Comment: Now that is quite right. My apologies.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with your second statement. Could you explain it? Could you also explain how the equation follows from that algebraically? Also, are you sure that $R-choose-r$ counts $r+1$ subsets of $\{0,1,2,...,R\}$, and not $r$ subsets of $\{1,2,...,R\}$?

Comment: It doesn't count all $r+1$-subsets of $\{0,1,2,\dots,R\}$, it counts $r+1$-subsets of $\{0,1,\dots,R\}$ which contain $R$.

Comment: Why is there an $N+1$ in the last formula of your first comment?  shouldn't it just be $N$? if it's just $N$, then there are $N-R$ elements in that set.

Comment: @Programmer2134 You are correct, that should be $\{R+1,R+2,\cdots,N\}$.

Comment: Is there a way to derive this algebraically, rather than through a conceptual argument? Also, what should I be studying if I want to understand things related to algebraic relations of the binomial coefficient? I have looked at a combinatorics book but it is very much focused on more general theories about vertices and stuff like that. I know the binomial coefficient applies to combinatorics, but what should I be studying to understand these algebraic relations without going into an exhaustive study of combinatorics?

Comment: The easiest algebraic proof is to use generating functions. Let $$f_M(x)=\frac{x^M}{(1-x)^{M+1}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k}{M}x^k.$$ Then you get $xf_{r}(x)f_{n-r}(x)=f_{n+1}(x)$ and equate the coefficients of $x^{N+1}$ on both sides.